# C program compiles and runs but skips if-else evaluation randomly when executed

Tags: c, if-statement

EDIT: Filled in complete code, sorry.

I am having trouble with a simple program that compiles and runs, but sometimes when it is executed it does not evaluate an if-else statement correctly and runs away into an infinite loop.

I thought it was pretty simple, straight-forward code, but for some reason it's buggy.

It is two structs of type Character evaluating an attack value and removing that amount from each of their health attributes in turn. It is supposed to evaluate whether the particular character's health is at or below 0 after adjusting the health value and exit the loop accordingly.

It worked fine when I wrote it with just one struct, but now that I have two structs in the function it seems to be hit or miss.

It all works correctly otherwise, the random attack value calculation, the adjustment of the health attribute, printing the struct info to console, but the loop doesn't always break, so it's not always evaluating to 'true' as it should.

Any thoughts on this on what may make this if-else evaluation sensitive?

Running Raspbian on Pi 3 B+

Compiling with gcc

Writing code in Visual Studio Code

Also compiled on ThinkPad running Ubuntu with same issue

Exact code

```
// main.c

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

#define WEAPON_INV_SIZE     5

/* Weapon, attack types */
enum Hand_type
{
    ONE_H,
    TWO_H,
    RANGED,
    MAGIC
};

struct Weapon
{
    char            name[64];
    int             level;
    int             minDamage;
    int             maxDamage;
    unsigned char   type;
};

/* Holds player current and maximum health amount */
struct Health
{
    unsigned int    currentHealth;
    unsigned int    maxHealth;
};

/* Holds player attributes */
struct Character
{
    char            name[64];
    unsigned int    expPoints;
    struct Health   health;

    float           attackBonus[4];

    struct Weapon * weaponInventory[WEAPON_INV_SIZE];
    struct Weapon * currentWeapon;
};

/* Holds weapon attributes */
struct Weapon * GetWeapon (char * name, int minDamage, int maxDamage, unsigned char type)
{
    struct Weapon * w = (struct Weapon *)malloc (sizeof(struct Weapon));
    strcpy (w->name, name);
    w->level = 1;
    w->minDamage = minDamage;
    w->maxDamage = maxDamage;
    w->type = type;
    return w;
}

/* Get random int from range between two ints */
int Random_Range (int lower, int greater)
{
    return (rand () % (greater - lower)) + lower;
}

/* Adjust character health */
void AdjustHealth (struct Character * character, int minAmount, int maxAmount)
{
    character->health.currentHealth += minAmount;
    character->health.maxHealth += maxAmount;
}


/* Two character battle sequence */
void Battle_2 (struct Character * char1, struct Character * char2)
{
    int min1 = (int)((float)char1->currentWeapon->minDamage * char1->attackBonus[char1->currentWeapon->type]);
    int max1 = (int)((float)char1->currentWeapon->maxDamage * char1->attackBonus[char1->currentWeapon->type]);
    int diff1 = max1 - min1;

    int min2 = (int)((float)char2->currentWeapon->minDamage * char2->attackBonus[char2->currentWeapon->type]);
    int max2 = (int)((float)char2->currentWeapon->maxDamage * char2->attackBonus[char2->currentWeapon->type]);
    int diff2 = max2 - min2;

    while (1)
    {
        AdjustHealth (char2, -(min1 + rand () % diff1), 0);

        if (char2->health.currentHealth <= 0)
        {
            printf ("Character 2 is dead!!!\n");
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            printf ("%3d/%3d : %3d/%3d\n",  char1->health.currentHealth, 
                                            char1->health.maxHealth,
                                            char2->health.currentHealth, 
                                            char2->health.maxHealth);
        }

        AdjustHealth (char1, -(min2 + rand () % diff2), 0);
        
        if (char1->health.currentHealth <= 0)
        {
            printf ("Character 1 is dead!!!\n");
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            printf ("%3d/%3d : %3d/%3d\n",  char1->health.currentHealth, 
                                            char1->health.maxHealth,
                                            char2->health.currentHealth, 
                                            char2->health.maxHealth);
        }
    }
    
}

int main ()
{
    srand (time (0));

    struct Character myChar01 = 
    {
        "My name",
        0,
        {100, 100},
        {1, 1.5, 1, .75},
        {},
        0
    };

    struct Character myChar02 = 
    {
        "Not my name",
        0,
        {100, 100},
        {1, 1.5, 1, .75},
        {},
        0
    };  

    /* Populate weapon inventory with new weapons */
    myChar01.weaponInventory[0] = GetWeapon ("Dagger", 1, 5, ONE_H);
    myChar01.weaponInventory[1] = GetWeapon ("Sword", 4, 8, TWO_H);
    myChar01.weaponInventory[2] = GetWeapon ("Wood Bow", 1, 6, RANGED);
    myChar01.weaponInventory[3] = GetWeapon ("Root Wand", 3, 7, MAGIC);

    /* Assign current weapons */
    myChar01.currentWeapon = myChar01.weaponInventory[0];
    myChar02.currentWeapon = myChar01.weaponInventory[2];

    /* Enter Battle sequence */
    Battle_2 (&myChar01, &myChar02);
    
    return 0;
    
}
```

Comment: Be kind to post [mcve]. The current code snippet is useless for someone wishing help you.

Comment: Since it is printing both character's current health every time through the loop, it should be clear what is happening from running the code -- either it will exit the loop when one of the health scores becomes negative, or the AdjustHealth routine is not reducing the health of one of the characters...

Comment: I'm going to guess there's some error in `AdjustHealth`, or more likely with how you create the characters.

Comment: Add lots of logging to your code until you can understand exactly what line of code is doing something you don't expect.

Comment: The 'if' statements inside the Battle_2 function are the issue. Everything else works as expected. I have now opened it up and complied on my Ubuntu laptop and it, too, runs correctly only half the times it is executed. Definitely the 'if' statements, definitely intermittent.

Comment: @AndrewGilbert its likely you have some kind of undefined behavior. There are tools that can help you narrow down exactly where the issue is, notably valgrind, address sanitizer, UBSan and gdb, probably in that order.

Comment: Making both members of `Health` type `int` will cure the problem identified in the answer by @dxiv

Comment: `{},` is not allowed in Standard C, there must be at least one initializer. (suggest writing `0`, or omitting entirely since trailing uninitialized members are initialized as if by 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    AdjustHealth(char2, -(min1 + rand() % diff1), 0);
```

This *de*creases the health of the character `char2->health.currentHealth` by some amount.

```
    if (char2->health.currentHealth <= 0)
```

This is supposed to end the battle when the health drops at or below 0.

***But*** because of the "*unsigned*" in `unsigned int currentHealth;` the `< 0` part can never hold, and the `if` condition only evaluates to true when `char2->health.currentHealth == 0`.

So the game continues until either character's health drops to *exactly* zero, which can take a long time if both `currentHealth` numbers wrapped around `0` to values in the `UINT_MAX` range.

Comment: Had it just been `< 0` a diagnostic would have been generated, but since `<= 0` can plausibly apply -- it sneaks by. Good eyes. Making both members of `Health` type `int` is an option.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin This was a sneaky one, indeed. Almost missed it on the double-take, too.

Comment: Other than that bit of `unsigned` behavior, it is a pretty clever little battle. Right now my Player1 has won 2/3 `:)`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin The other hidden lesson in here is that OP's edit where the complete code was added moved the question from hopeless to solvable, or even +1'able ;-)

Comment: That fixed the issue. The members of struct health did not need to be unsigned. Thank you for catching that, it was driving me nuts.